# Distributing .mdf files to field sites

Tags: sql, sql-server, localdb

I am trying to find the best procedure to get data from our SQL server at headquarters to update apps running on local machines in various locations not connected to our network. Our current data and application is in Foxpro where you simply copied the data file, so I am not very familiar with using SQL databases.

The field app uses localdb and users don't save anything to the database. When the app opens it checks a web site to for updates. I tried detaching our HQ .mdf and .ldf, downloading it and overwriting it on the local machine, but localdb would not attach to the new file (same name). I thought localdb closes and detaches when the application closes , but maybe I am wrong. I also wonder if I need the log file since no changes are made and I dont need to rollback anything. I have searched for a good article on this topic but haven't found anything. This must be a fairly common scenario in many companies.

Answer (score 0):

You want to look into using replication, probably snapshot replication. This allows you to distribute on whatever schedule  is applicable to send one or more tables, or other objects, to off site sql server instances. You can use Http to send data.